# google analytics Tracker on 2 submit button

Tags: forms, button, google-analytics, submit

Hello i'm lost about my tracking button

I have 2 form pop in fancybox

but in analytics when i fill one form for exemple the quotation, the tracker shows the 2 label as if i have fill the 2 form.

I don't understand why.

I want to differenciate the 2 submit button for tracking.

Comment: post your code so we can see what's wrong, its how you integrate the tracking code to the form.

Answer (score 0):

script google analytics at the end of the html page:

ga('send', 'pageview');
  ga('send', 'event', 'rajasthanpop-fr-devis', 'click-rajasthan-devis', 'devis-envoye');
  ga('send', 'event', 'rajasthanpop-fr-infos', 'click-rajasthan-infos', 'infos-envoye');

first input :

input style="width:100% !important;" class="btn btn-info pull-left"  name="submit" id="submitButton"  type="submit" value="Envoyer" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'rajasthanpop-fr-infos', 'click-rajasthan-infos', 'infos-envoye');"

second input : 
input style="width:100% !important;" class="btn btn-info pull-left"  name="submit" id="submitButton"  type="submit" value="Envoyer" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'rajasthanpop-fr-devis', 'click-rajasthan-devis', 'devis-envoye');"